# Match (closest) value, starting from the end of a range

Tags: excel, match, worksheet-function

What formula (no VBA) could I use if I want to find a value of which I do not know the exact value within the range? So lets say I want to find the value closest to "2", starting from the end of the range.

```
A   B
1   1.45
2   2.03
3   3.40
4   3.01
5   1.94
6   0.99
```

The answer would be "5" in this case.

Edit1: I noticed that my question needed more explanation. So here it goes. I'm not only interested in the closest matching value at the **end** of the range, but also the one at the **start** of the range. In other words, I want to get both "2" and "5" from the example above. Since it wasn't hard to get the value at the start of the range, I needed help only with getting the one at the end of the range. But any suggestion to get either or both of these values is appreciated.

I cannot sort the data, because the data is also used for other purposes.

Edit2: I think I have found a way, correct me if I'm wrong. The formula became a little long so I broke it down in pieces.

```
MAX(
    INDEX(A,
          MATCH(
                 SMALL(ABS(B-$C$1),1),
                 ABS(B-$C$1),
                 0
               )
         )
    INDEX(A,
          MATCH(
                 SMALL(ABS(B-$C$1),2),
                 ABS(B-$C$1),
                 0
               )
         )
   )
```

The MAX Function will spit out the highest value of A by calling 2 almost equal functions of which the first will find the closest value to the lookup value and the second will find the second closest value to the lookup value.

Comment: Somehow you have to perform a (Array.)BinarySearch

Comment: Note that 2.05 and 1.95 are equally close to 2

Comment: Is there a reason that would mean you cannot sort your data?

Comment: @RowlandShow, Exactly as pnuts says, because you lose track of whether 2.05 was on the ascending part of the range or the descending part.

Answer (score 3):

[This answer assumes that the data in column A are monotonically increasing]

Put your number to test (in your case, 2) in $C$1. (I've assumed your input table is aligned in A1:B6)

Then, in another cell, write:

```
=MAX(IF(ABS(ABS(B1:B6-$C$1)-MIN(ABS(B1:B6-$C$1)) < 0.00000000000001), A1:A6, 0))
```

This is an **array** formula; you need to press Ctrl + Shift + Return once you've edited.

(It uses a trick with an `IF` statement extended to arrays, emitting only the minimum value(s) and the `MAX` picks the larger index as per the question spec. The small number is there as a workaround to imprecisions in Excel's floating point type.)

Array formulas in Excel are *extremely* powerful.

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestion. it works great with the example I gave you but I noticed that my example was flawed. As you pointed out, 2.05 and 1.95 are equally close to 2. In case I change 1.95 to 1.94, the formula suddenly returns 2, which is not what I want. I'd like to get the value closest to the requested value, on both ends of the ascend and descend.

Comment: Your formula finds the 2.03 value since it is closest to the lookup value. I'm looking for the value closest to the lookup value from the other side of the curve. I updated my question where I discuss a solution that has worked so far. What do you think?

Comment: I'll have a play tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a way, correct me if I'm wrong. The formula became a little long so I broke it down in pieces.

```
MAX(
    INDEX(A,
          MATCH(
                 SMALL(ABS(B-$C$1),1),
                 ABS(B-$C$1),
                 0
               )
         )
    INDEX(A,
          MATCH(
                 SMALL(ABS(B-$C$1),2),
                 ABS(B-$C$1),
                 0
               )
         )
   )
```

The MAX Function will spit out the highest value of A by calling 2 almost equal functions of which the first will find the closest value to the lookup value and the second will find the second closest value to the lookup value.

Answer (score -1):

You can use VLOOKUP:

> Vlookup is one of the most popular look up functions in Excel.  When
>   you need to extract data from a table based on a particular value, you
>   can use Vlookup to do that.

http://www.spreadsheetsmadeeasy.com/how-use-vlookup-excel/

*Look at example "Vlookup when searching for numbers"

[image]

Let’s look at some of the return values by playing around with the Vlookup formula.  I’ll do a Vlookup on a temperature of 0.03 using this formula:

=VLOOKUP(0.03,$A$2:$B$8,2,TRUE)

Result: "Ridiculously Cold"

The way Excel steps through this formula is similar to the last one we looked at:

> It starts by looking at the table’s first column for a value of 0.03
>   or something close (approximate). Starts with 0.01.  Since 0.01 is
>   less than 0.03, it moves to the next one. Then it looks at 32.  Since
>   32 is greater than 0.03, it reverts back to 0.01 as the closest match.
>   Now it goes to column 2 and return the corresponding value next to
>   0.01′s value, which is “Ridiculously Cold.”

Comment: That's right there you have a point... I will look for another solution.

Comment: @pnuts Hopefully the OP *can* sort their data (not stated that they can't)

Comment: Should I delete this answer?